# I have used DatePeriod for preparing dates b/w two dates but not working

Tags: php

How can we prepare dates between two dates in php?

I have searched and found a method using DatePeriod. I had tried with this method but result is getting different one.

```
DatePeriod Object
(
    [start] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2017-11-23 02:09:17.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
        )

    [current] => 
    [end] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2017-11-23 05:09:17.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
        )

    [interval] => DateInterval Object
        (
            [y] => 0
            [m] => 0
            [d] => 1
            [h] => 0
            [i] => 0
            [s] => 0
            [weekday] => 0
            [weekday_behavior] => 0
            [first_last_day_of] => 0
            [invert] => 0
            [days] => 
            [special_type] => 0
            [special_amount] => 0
            [have_weekday_relative] => 0
            [have_special_relative] => 0
        )

    [recurrences] => 1
    [include_start_date] => 1
)
```

Date is passing from jquery post.

```
<?php
$dates       = '02.09.17 - 05.09.17';
$daterange   = explode(" - ", $dates);
$dateBegin   = $daterange[0];
$dateEnd     = $daterange[1];

$period      = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($daterange[0]), new DateInterval('P1D'), new DateTime($daterange[1]));                

print_r($period);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the format when creating the DateTime objects. As you can see it's putting your date strings in the time portion. Do something like this instead:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y', '02.09.17');
```

or more specifically:

```
$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y', $daterange[0]);
$to = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y', $daterange[1]);
$period = new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('P1D'), $to);
```

By the way, I'm not sure if your format is **'d.m.y'** or **'m.d.y'**, so adjust as appropriate.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it :)